# Xcode Build Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I've been having some trouble with Xcode. Every time I launch my application, it opens in the simulator and then immediately closes. Xcode says it build successfully and there are no errors.

This happened when I added a timer to my application, however I have now reverted to the previous save where there is no mention of this timer and I *know it was working then, but it still happens the same way.

Does anyone else get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search on SO for the debug flag to turn on in XCode so that you get a stack trace on program exit (I can't find it and my mac machine is not available)

It's NSZombieEnabled, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726603/debugging-exc-bad-access-in-an-iphone-app)